# Change row value qlikview

Tags: qlikview

```
IF(LEVEL2 = '16.30' AND (len(LEVEL3 > '0')), LEVEL2, LEVEL1)  AS LEVEL4
```

When I load this line, it will output in a pivot table showing 16.3 because in my excel sheet that I load from, 16.30 is shown as 16.3 (For I don't know what reason. My company say it's like that).

What I would like to do is to change the 16.3 showing in the pivot table to '16.30'. Is there any way I can do it like for example

```
IF(LEVEL2 = '16.30' AND (len(LEVEL3 > '0')), LEVEL2 AS '16.30', LEVEL1)  AS LEVEL4
```

The above code does not work btw. Thank very much.

Comment: Is it 16.3 a value in a table? In that case go to Properties -> Number and then use Number format setting: "Fixed to 2 decimals".

Answer (score 0):

This line does not make sense

```
IF(LEVEL2 = '16.30' AND (len(LEVEL3 > '0')), LEVEL2 AS '16.30', LEVEL1)  AS LEVEL4
```

Change to

```
IF(LEVEL2 = '16.30' AND len(LEVEL3) > '0', LEVEL2 AS '16.30', LEVEL1)  AS LEVEL4
```

And to get the correct value formatted properly you would use

```
Num(IF(LEVEL2 = '16.30' AND len(LEVEL3) > '0', LEVEL2 AS '16.30', LEVEL1),'# ##0.00')  AS LEVEL4
```